# Counting to the future.

Tags: statistics

Thought I'd post this here instead of coding forums.

What I'm trying to achieve is kind of new to me. Basically it goes something like this:

I have a counter that, well...counts. I also have a timer that times when the counter goes up. What I need is equation an that gives me the time when the counter reaches a set level based on past data.

So for example:

At 09:11:45 am, 1 was added to the counter. Running count: 1

At 09:15:07 am, 4 was added to the counter. Running count: 5

At 09:24:25 am, 8 was added to the counter. Running count: 13

At 09:24:54 am, 1 was added to the counter. Running count: 14

At 09:45:57 am, 2 was added to the counter. Running count: 16 and so on...

I would like to know at what time will the counter reach 20?
How do I calculate this?

If I want to google this topic what is this called? I'm not sure where to start.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: This cannot be serious, obviously it must be 09:53:17 am, right?

Comment: I think that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation can help.